# mysql UPDATE subquery using SUM

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

Can you please guide me why below query is not working ?

thanks

```
UPDATE campaigns SET available='0' WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id, sum(stock_qty) AS qty FROM `sku_colors_sizes` GROUP BY product_id HAVING sum(stock_qty) < 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select only one column from the subquery to compare it using the `IN` predicate, you can modify it so that only the `product_id` is selected, something like this:

```
UPDATE campaigns 
SET available='0'
WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id -- <=====
                     FROM
                     (
                       SELECT product_id, sum(stock_qty) AS qty 
                       FROM sku_colors_sizes 
                       GROUP BY product_id 
                       HAVING sum(stock_qty) < 1
                     ) AS t)
```